# GetCoockie from appengine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, httpurlconnection

hey i've written a server in app engine. i've used so far the HttpDefaultClient in order to do so.

```
 protected Boolean doInBackground(String... tokens) {

        try {

            // Don't follow redirects
            params.setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, false);

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://" + appId
                    + ".appspot.com/_ah/login?continue=http://" + appId + ".appspot.com/&auth=" + tokens[0]);

            response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
            out.close();

            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 302){
                // Response should be a redirect
                return false;
            }

            //check if we received the ACSID or the SACSID cookie, depends on http or https request
            for(Cookie cookie : httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies()) {
                if(cookie.getName().equals("ACSID") || cookie.getName().equals("SACSID")){
                    return true;
                }
            }

        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            cancel(true);
        } finally {
            params.setBooleanParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS, true);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

does any one knows how do i get the same coockie via other connection??

i know how to recieve the token : by httpUrlconnection:

```
     private String getAuthToken() {

            AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(
                    mAccount, "ah", null, true, null, null);
            Bundle bundle;
            try {
                bundle = future.getResult(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (OperationCanceledException | IOException | AuthenticatorException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected error while getting an auth token: ", e);
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            return bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
        }

:
    private URL getAuthUrl(String token) {
        api = "http://" + appId+ ".appspot.com/_ah/login?continue=http://" + appId + ".appspot.com/&auth=" + token;
        String path = Uri.parse(mBaseUrl)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendEncodedPath("_ah/login")
                .appendQueryParameter("continue", mBaseUrl)
                .appendQueryParameter("auth", token)
                .build()
                .toString();

        try {
            return new URL(api);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
private String getAuthCookie(URL authUrl) {
        HttpURLConnection conn = ((HttpURLConnection) authUrl.openConnection());
        String cookie = conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie"); // returns null!
        return cookie;

}
```

any idea why?? and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure a cookie is being set for your second example?

Comment: no...how do i set it?? I mean i have no idea. at the first example, it was added automatically. i thought it be automatically in here as well isn't?

Comment: If it isn't there for the second request then the server is not sending the header

Comment: i don't understand. so what i need to add? @JoshTriiJohnston

Answer (score 1):

i've recieved : NID=72=bIkTJcJ1o1iX988WeqjEhAELifvxtDOoD0sIe-VqZQK0ToezFvDSx0ctjko8KZyJYA7S1aAyl-7WYh6Wue-UHhSJYgXSQg9NrFXEMjUujONGIomcrSsX5373zYb59oBI; expires=Thu, 07-Apr-2016 22:56:30 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly

answer :

```
 package com.example.daniel.testing9;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.accounts.AccountManagerFuture;
import android.accounts.AuthenticatorException;
import android.accounts.OperationCanceledException;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * AppEngine authentication with a Google account works as follows:
 1. First we obtain a token from the Google account on device.
 2. We authenticate with Appengine at /_ah/login URL
 3. If authentication is successful, an ACSID (SACSID for https) cookie is set
 4. If the token has expired (default 24 hours), then we invalidate it and try again.
 5. Set the [S]ACSID cookie on future requests, e.g.:
 HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
 conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie);
 */
public class AuthHelper {
    private static final String TAG = "auth";
    public static boolean finished = false;
    private final AccountManager mAccountManager;
    private final Account mAccount;
    private final String mBaseUrl;
    private static String _cookie = null;
    String appId;
    String api;
    String token;
    static AuthHelper instance = null;
    public static AuthHelper getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.context.getApplicationContext());
            accountManager = AccountManager.get(MainActivity.context.getApplicationContext());

            // assembling all gmail accounts
            Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");

            // add all gmail accounts :
            ArrayList<String> accountList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (Account account : accounts) {
                accountList.add(account.name);
            }

            Account account = accounts[0];
            instance = new AuthHelper(accountManager, account, Constants.SERVER_REQUESTS.MY_APP_WEBSITE,
                    Constants.SERVER_REQUESTS.MY_APP_ID);
        }
        return instance;
    }
    public AuthHelper(@NonNull AccountManager accountManager,
                            @NonNull Account account,
                            @NonNull String appspotBaseUrl, String appid) {
        mAccountManager = accountManager;
        mAccount = account;
        mBaseUrl = appspotBaseUrl;
        this.appId = appid;
    }


    public String getAuthPath(String url) {
        if (token == null) {
            token = getAuthToken();
        }
       return  api = Constants.SERVER_REQUESTS.MY_APP_WEBSITE+"_ah/login?continue="+url+"&auth=" + token;
    }
    public String authenticateAndGetCookie() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            token = getAuthToken();
            URL authUrl = getAuthUrl(token);
            String cookie = getAuthCookie(authUrl);
            if (cookie != null) {
                _cookie = cookie;
                return cookie;
            }
            invalidateAuthToken(token);
        }

        return null;
    }
    private String getAuthCookie(URL authUrl) {
        try {
            HttpURLConnection conn = ((HttpURLConnection) authUrl.openConnection());
            return conn.getHeaderField("Set-Cookie");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private URL getAuthUrl(String token) {
        api = "http://" + appId+ ".appspot.com/_ah/login?continue=http://" + appId + ".appspot.com/&auth=" + token;
        String path = Uri.parse(mBaseUrl)
                .buildUpon()
                .appendEncodedPath("_ah/login")
              //  .appendQueryParameter("continue", mBaseUrl)
                .appendQueryParameter("auth", token)
                .build()
                .toString();

        try {
            return new URL(path);
            //return new URL(api);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private String getAuthToken() {

        AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future = mAccountManager.getAuthToken(
                mAccount, "ah", null, true, null, null);
        Bundle bundle;
        try {
            bundle = future.getResult(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (OperationCanceledException | IOException | AuthenticatorException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unexpected error while getting an auth token: ", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        return bundle.getString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN);
    }

    private void invalidateAuthToken(String token) {
        mAccountManager.invalidateAuthToken(mAccount.type, token);
        finished = true;
    }


}
```